# Unable to position different list items inside article tag in HTML, CSS

Tags: css, html

I want to show some information together inside an article tag. After searching and seeing quite a handful of examples, I decided to show the information in **inlined list items**. Here is how I am going to do that.[image] Just look at number 1 and 2. My end result is preferably number 1. I have displayed number 2 just to see how much space other elements like `<p> </p>` takes.

This is the [css](http://pastebin.com/4VCW5VqF) code. Here is the [html](http://pastebin.com/N5R2akAh) code that uses this css. The list items are taking more spaces and i want the box to remain in the size like number 2. So I think it will be better if the extra yellow space could be minimized.

I have tried using separate divs for the 3 list items. That didn't help. I am new in using CSS. Any idea how I can save the spaces and make it look good enough?

Update: After adding

```
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

}
```

Currently it looks like this:[image]
Improved significantly. Any idea how to minimize spaces on the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing is due to the default top and bottom margins of ul elements, of 16px.
**Update:** Final Solution

```
ul { 
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

I would set these to 0 initially to prove that this is the issue, then increase them to something reasonable.

The font-size is slightly bigger (for the li's) as well.

Comment: To reduce the space on the left, remove or reduce `padding-left` for the ul, which has a default of 40px.

Comment: works like charm :) wasn't aware of the default values. thanks!